# Were sermons in the Middle Ages devoted to Old Testament or New Testament subjects?

Tags: middle-ages, religion

Were they more often devoted to New Testament subjects or to Old Testament subjects?

Comment: This question is rather broad. What specifically do you want to know. Also, are you asking about sermons of the Roman Catholic Church?

Comment: @Luke: Yes, the Catholic Church. I'm mostly interested in the second question, but any subsidiary information will be welcome.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the question doesn't really have any limits on it right now. If you could make it clear in the question what specifically you want to know, that would be great.

Comment: @Luke: I narrowed it down a bit - is it better now?

Comment: Any specific area or time period of the Middle Ages? Aside from that it seems better. I'm curious to hear from the downvoters themselves. Downvoting a question that is not obviously spam without leaving a comment to explain is rather rude.

Comment: geographic limits, time limits, monasteries, for which estate, in Universities?.  There's a lot more specification required.

Comment: @SamuelRussell: I agree that specification is good,, but on the other hand there is so little known about this topic (I think!) that I feel a somewhat wider net has to be cast to get something.

Comment: Wow, +4,-3, that's one hell of a contentious question :) Downvoters, out there - please tell me what you think.

Comment: You can't ask an absolute comparative in a thousand year period covering the entirety of europe and a significant part of North Africa and Asia when there isn't sufficient material to cover any specified question.  It is a poorly researched question.

Comment: @SamuelRussell: I am just trying to find out if there is *something* known about this...

Comment: It has been a while since I last sat through a sermon or considered homiletics, but I believe the question includes a false dichotomy.  The sermon isn't constrained to a Testament; it is quite possible to preach a sermon on "how to cook an egg while one handed" (I sat through that sermon).  Sermons should be about the Churches relationship with God, which includes both OT & NT.

Answer (score 4):

There are trivially googleable results, which if consulted, could allow this question to become a question worth answering:
http://hcl.harvard.edu/libraries/houghton/collections/early_manuscripts/preaching/

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think that preaching sermons really developed until the Renaissance with Girolamo Savonarola and the Protestant Reformation. Up to that point, I believe that Catholic services consisted exclusively of performing the Seven Sacraments. In Mass, I believe that, generally, only prayers would be said.

Comment: THat'd be great to know, but do you have a source? I am no expert on this so I can neither correct you nor aseent to your stetement. +1 anyway for the angle